# Environment Variable persistence

Tags: 16.04, bash, java, environment-variables, jdk

I am having trouble with my environment variables not persisting.

Background: I originally installed Java using a ppa and apt-get install. But then later decided I need another JDK than what the ppa gave me and manually installed another version.

I set `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment` and ran `source /etc/environment` and then `echo $JAVA_HOME` and got `/path/to/new/JDK`.

When I close the terminal and reopen it and run `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get `/path/to/old/JDK`.

How do I get my environment variables to persist?

Here is my /etc/environment file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME:$CATALINA_HOME:$GRAILS_HOME/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/home/android272/.jabba/jdk/current"
JRE_HOME="$JAVA_HOME/jre"
GRAILS_HOME="/home/android272/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current"
CATALINA_HOME="/opt/tomcat/tomcat8"
```

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME defined in your personal `~/.bashrc`, the global bashrc at `/etc/bash.bashrc`, or `/etc/profile` (as well as `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`)?

Comment: Terminals don't open login shells by default - they *inherit* the login environment from the session. So next time you login, it should all "just work"

Comment: @KazWolfe I don't seem to have JAVA_HOME defined in any of those places.

Comment: @steeldriver I have also restarted and ran `echo $JAVA_HOME` and have the same result.

Comment: In that case, please tell us exactly *how* you set it in your /etc/environment file (it's not usually sourced, so that might explain why you see a difference in behavior)

Comment: I just posted my /etc/environment file. If that is not what you asking for then let me know.

Comment: Do you need to [`export`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411455/what-does-export-do-in-shell-programming) your variables?

Comment: That's not correct. `/etc/environment` does not enpand variables.  Please see [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables).

Comment: @earthmeLon: Bad advice. `/etc/environment` is not a script file - no `export`.

Comment: @earthmeLon I don't know I am new to Linux environment variables.

Comment: @AndrewPullins your /etc/environment looks OK to me (although personally I would have made the changes in a personal .profile). The only explanation I can think of is that JAVA_HOME is getting reset elsewhere (e.g. in ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, or ~/.bash_profile).

Comment: @steeldriver Ok how do I set these? because ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile look nothing like a file with environment variables and ~/.bash_profile does not exist. These files have a bunch of code that I do not understand.

Comment: @AndrewPullins As Gunnar has mentioned above and quoted from the link supplied `Note: Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment.` Therefore, your JRE_HOME variable is invalid. You need to replace `$JAVA_HOME` with `/home/android272/.jabba/jdk/current`